# How to edit file's attributes in windows with python (specially for Microsoft office files : docx, ppt, xlsx ...)

Tags: python, file, attributes, ms-office, metadata

I've been looking on the net for a specific **python module** that could allow me to **modify file's attribute** that windows display in the properties window. To be more specific I would like to **edit the company name** displayed (see the picture below - sorry for the french).

Thank you for any piece of advice or help given.

[windows' file properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHe8F.png)